# R decision tree error message

Tags: r, runtime-error, decision-tree

I have an error message when make predictions with an decision tree that I don't know how to intrepret:

```
library(DMwR)
library(rpart.plot)
train <-na.omit(train)
test <-na.omit(test)


ar <- rpartXse(Survived ~ .,train)

prp(dt,type=4,extra=101)

pre <- predict(ar,test,type='class')
```

Error:

```
5.
stop(sprintf(ngettext(length(m), "factor %s has new level %s", "factor %s    has new levels %s"), nm, paste(nxl[m], collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
4.
model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = attr(object, "xlevels"))
3.
model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = attr(object, "xlevels"))
2.
predict.rpart(ar, test, type = "class")
1.
predict(ar, test, type = "class")
```

At first I think it was by have NA values I correct that, don't worked.

Someone can tell me how to interpret messages of this kind and how can I correct it please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your test data has some factor levels that aren't present in your training data, so your model doesn't know what to do with them. The actual error message should tell you what column has the problem, but the `traceback()` results don't.

Comment: For corrections, you can either (a) make sure that your training data has at least one record for every category, or (b) pre-process your test data to set any new categories as missing, or (c) pre-process all the data to make lump uncommmon categories together into a single "other" category.

Comment: thanks I notice now the test case is all columns except the class to predict